# Perl read Gmail and parse the attachments- successful on my PC but failed on another one

Tags: regex, perl, email, gmail, firewall

I cooked up a script to check the arrival of an email (read Gmail) coming from a specified user with specified subject title using regular expression and . If it matches, it will download the attachment to an output location.

The Perl module I used is Mail::POP3Client (to get connection) and MIME::Parser (to parse attachments). The email server I am working on is Gmail.

However, strange thing happens. It work on my PC, but fails on another PC! You could download the code and replace those ARGV[i] with your personal info and try running that cod;

If the returned number of emails are not '-1', it means connection successful.

It's very strange that this code works on my pc but failed on another PC (always display -1 emails)! I'm thinking, is it because the Perl module installation is wrong or because the mail was blocked by firewall?

The error message is:
There are [-1] emails!

The codes are:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mail::POP3Client;
use MIME::Parser;
use MIME::Entity;
use File::Copy;
use File::Glob ':glob';

my ($DAY,$MONTH,$YEAR);
my $host   = 'pop.gmail.com';
my $user   = $ARGV[0];
my $passwd = $ARGV[1];
my $sender =$ARGV[2];
my $outputloc=$ARGV[3];
my $subject=$ARGV[4];
my $attachedfile=$ARGV[5];
my $outfile=$ARGV[6];
my $today=return_time();
my $flag=0;

$attachedfile =~s/date/$today/g;
$outfile =~s/date/$today/g;


my $client = new Mail::POP3Client(
    USER     => $user,
    PASSWORD => $passwd,
    HOST     => "pop.gmail.com",
    PORT     => 995,
    USESSL   => 'true',
);
my $parser = MIME::Parser->new;
$parser->output_dir("T:/dailyfiles/TEMP");
my $mgrnum = $client->Count;
print "There are [$mgrnum] emails!\n";

for ( my $i = 1 ; $i <= $mgrnum ; $i++ ) {
    my $headandbody = $client->HeadAndBody($i);
    my $entity = $parser->parse_data($headandbody);
    $parser->decode_headers(1);
    my $Subject=$entity->head->get('Subject');
    my $From=$entity->head->get('From');
    my $To=$entity->head->get('To');
    my $Date=$entity->head->get('Date');
    my $MIME_type=$entity->mime_type;
    print "From      = ",$From;
    print "To        = ",$To;
    print "Cc        = ",$entity->head->get('Cc'),"\n";
    print "Subject   = ",$Subject;
    print "Date      = ",$Date;
    print "MIME type = ",$entity->mime_type,"\n";
    print "Parts     = ",scalar $entity->parts,"\n";
    print "=========================================================\n";
    exit if ( (scalar $entity->parts) == 1 );
    chomp($Subject);
    chomp($From);

    if($Subject eq $subject && $From eq $sender) {
      chdir "T:/dailyfiles/TEMP"; 
      my @list = bsd_glob('*.txt');
      my @list2 = bsd_glob('*.html');
      unlink(@list,@list2); 
      my $dir="T:/dailyfiles/TEMP/";
      opendir(DIR,$dir) or die$!;
      while(defined(my $file=readdir DIR)){
       my $oldfile=$file;
       if($file =~/$attachedfile/){
        $flag=1;
        print "Original Attachment: $oldfile\n";
        print "Renamed Attachment: ",$outfile,"\n";
        if (-e $outfile) {
          warn "can't rename $oldfile to $outfile: $file exists ";
       } elsif (rename $oldfile, $outfile) {
       } else {
         warn "rename $oldfile to $outfile failed:$! ";
      }
       ## copy and move files
       move("T:/dailyfiles/TEMP/$outfile",$outputloc.$outfile);
       print "STATUS: Required email arrival. Expected attachment forwarded to $outputloc.\n";
       print "=========================================================\n";
    }
} 
     if($flag==0){
     print "STATUS: Required email arrival. However, attachment is disqualified.\n";    
    }
    }
    else{
     print "STATUS: Required email not yet come. Try later.\n";
    }
}

delete_dir();  

##subroutines go here
sub return_time{
    ($DAY,$MONTH,$YEAR)=(gmtime)[3,4,5];
     $today=sprintf("%04d%02d%02d",$YEAR+1900,$MONTH+1,$DAY);
     return $today;  
}

sub delete_dir{
my $dir="T:/dailyfiles/TEMP/";
opendir(DIR,$dir) or die$!;
while(defined(my $file=readdir DIR)){
    unlink($dir.$file);
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading Mail::POP3Client documentation, I see that you should check youк POP3 connection after creating an object. The error you receive indicates that connection error occured:

> new returns a valid Mail::POP3Client object in all cases. To test for
>   a connection failure, you will need to check the number of messages:
>   -1 indicates a connection error. This will likely change sometime in the future to return undef on an error, setting $! as a side effect.
>   This change will not happen in any 2.x version.

You can do it like that:

```
my $client = new Mail::POP3Client(
  USER     => $user,
  PASSWORD => $passwd,
  HOST     => "pop.gmail.com",
  PORT     => 995,
  USESSL   => 'true',
);
die "Can't connect to the server" if $client->Count == -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to track errors:

```
my $client = new Mail::POP3Client(
    USER     => $user,
    PASSWORD => $passwd,
    HOST     => "pop.gmail.com",
    PORT     => 995,
    USESSL   => 'true',
) || die $!;
#  ^^^^^^^^^ insert this and you will show connection error
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of the modules that you are using.